# Start AppleScript Script from Java on Mac OSX

Tags: java, macos, applescript

I try to execute a JavaScript Script with the Code

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("osascript /Path/To/Script.scpt");

In Terminal the command osascript /Path/To/Script.scpt works fine and the script do ist job but in java nothing happens. I try other commands with Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd) and they all work.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by myself:

```
String script = "tell application \"System Events\"" + "\n" + "keystroke \"h\" using command down" + "\n" + "end tell";
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("AppleScript");
engine.eval(script);
```

is the new way to execute AppleScripts.